# Open Gmail PendingIntent in background?

Tags: android, notifications, gmail, android-pendingintent

I am trying to open a PendingIntent that opens the Gmail App in the background through a notification.

The steps are as follows:

1. Show notification with action button
2. On click of action button (which has a PendingIntent), I want start the PendingIntent (which launches the Gmail app) but in the background.
3. Dismiss Notification

The notification remains the only thing that the user has seen (i.e. the UI has not changed but only the notification has itself been dismissed after clicking the action button).

It may be "hack-y" but I could also quickly open and then "minimize" the gmail app?

Any ideas?

Comment: What would opening the Gmail app in the background accomplish?

Comment: Does this even work when you open it in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I really don't understand what you can achieve from such behavior.

you definitely could not provide any meaningful extra data on the intent (unless you are the developer of gmail, which I don't believe is the case..).

actually, if you provides intent to launch explicitly Gmail app (by specifying the package name) - your code would break if Gmail app package name would change.

**now to your question:**

it is possible to launch activity without bringing it to foreground:

all you have to do is add to the intent been held by the pending intent to flags: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and  [FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` flag is not recommended for use unless your application is the launcher.

gmail main activity would create in background new task, and that's it.

note that the gmail activity would not go threw the `onResume` and `onStart` callbacks (because it's not on foreground..) , so if any meaningful code happens from this callbacks - they won't be executed anyway..

**UPDATE**

now that I know that your purpose is to mark an emails as "read", I can tell you that any attempts to launch gmail app want do to you any good. as I mentioned, you can't pass extra meaningful data to gamil launching intent. there is simply no such API's,  and launching main activity simply won't do anything that would help you.

instead, I'll suggest you to use [Gmail API's](https://developers.google.com/gmail/) for control user's inbox

Comment: My intent is to fool gmail into marking an emails as "read" by opening up the intent to that email in the bg...would this still work?

Comment: @Rohan: it won't work for sure. that's because launching gmail main activity not marking mail as read until user click on the mail itself.

Comment: @Rohan: If you wish to manage somehow users gamil messages from your own app - you should use Gmail API's - https://developers.google.com/gmail/